# Is there a way to include Django ModelForm in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I need to include a Django ModelForm in a dynamically created element in JavaScript.

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['body']
        widgets = {
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Compose your post here...', 'rows':3})
        }
```

I want to include the above form inside of the container div

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.innnerHTML = "<div></div>";
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could render your form to `<template>` and then access it from js.

```
<template>
    {{ form }}
</template>
```

Now from js file you can access above element and put it inside some other container. Template tag is hidden so it won't appear on your page.